# Active Admin Formtastic: dynamic has_many inputs without a table?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, jsonb, formtastic

I'm using Formtastic as part of Active Admin in Rails

I'd like to use the dynamic form builder (adding and removing elements with buttons).  Normally this would be done with `has_many` inputs, but I am saving to a jsonb array in the database rather than a true has_many relationship

I can set up custom setter methods in the model to accommodate this, but I don't know where to start. I can't use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on a jsonb attribute.

In my Active Admin page, if I try to add

```
f.inputs "General Contact" do
  f.has_many :phone_numbers
...
```

(where phone_numbers is a jsonb attribute)
I get an error

> undefined method 'new_record?' for nil:NilClass

Is this possible?

Comment: Out of the box this is not possible. But perhaps using this gem: https://github.com/DmitryTsepelev/store_model can help out laying the connection between formtastic inputs for the jsonb value and the corresponding model.